# how can I change the shape of scroller with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got confused how other front end developers can they change the scroller shape of web page in order to make it good look
how can I use JS to make this happens?

Comment: You need to be clear what you require, including code

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to do your own research prior to asking here. (And when you do ask here, you are still expected to put more effort into your question than you did so far.)

Comment: https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)

From their example:

```
<style>
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #b30000; 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you need to use JavaScript to achieve this?

This can be implemented quite simply using css:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 3em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```